# How can I solve this strange VS 2010 form design view issue?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The problem: In VS2010, I have a form with a broken design view.  It's breaking on a couple of Atalasoft imageviewer controls.

The weirdness: Took me some time to figure this out, but if I go into the forms designer.vb file, and comment out everything regarding these controls, save, uncomment, and save again, the form design view loads perfect.  NOTE: I'm not changing anything.  Just commenting/uncommenting portions of the designer and saving.

The form design view continues to work fine until I do any of the following:

1. close the form design view and the designer.vb file and try to view again.
2. close the solution and reopen.

After doing either of these things, it's back to square one and I have to comment/uncomment/save to view the form designer again.

I'm on Win7, 64 bit.  I have worked on this app in the past with no issue.  The app builds and runs just fine.  It's just a VS form design view issue, and I'm flummoxed.

I'd love to hear any thoughts on how I can solve this.  If I can provide any more specific info, please let me know.

Comment: I assume this only happens with the Atalasoft controls on the form (ie. if you remove them you won't have this issue at all).  Have you tried creating a brand new form with only these controls on it? If it breaks on that, I'd go to them as it's most likely a fault with their controls.

Comment: You haven't explained what failure looks like, surely there's some kind of diagnostic.  Nevertheless, this is bound to be an issue with those controls having a problem switching in and out of design mode.  Contact the vendor for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen rarely, when something odd gets into the designer file for a form and the designer can't figure out how to display things anymore. A third-party control being part of it *could* be indicative of some bug with that control's designer-related code.

One thing to try might be re-creating the form in question from scratch, and see if that fixes it. Perhaps something inadvertently got fubared. Also see if there is anything out there with others having designer problems with the same control(s) in question.

Sorry can't offer more direct help; maybe someone else has experienced something more closely related.

Comment: I'm less concerned with how the control is causing an issue and more concerned about why commenting/uncommenting/saving in the form designer.vb file would cause the design viewer to work afterwards.  And why that wouldn't persist after it was closed again.  This might be too much of a goose-chase.  I'll try recreating it, but it's a complex form and that's going to be a pain.

Comment: Yeah, usually that is a big pain. :(

Comment: Marking this as the answer because I've never nailed it down any further, and it does appear to have something to do with the third party control.